# Kubectl create error "could not find expected"

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, kubernetes, yaml

I'm using kbuernetes version 1.20.5 with docker 19.03.8 on a virtual machine. I'm trying to create a test elk cluster with kubernetes. When i enter kubectl create i get the followig error:

```
error parsing testserver.yaml: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: line 17: could not find expected ':'
```

I keep checking but can't find where the missing ":" should be. I validated the yaml in yaml lint and i get valid yaml result. The yaml file is like this:

```
#namespace define
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: testlog

---
#esnodes
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode1
  name: testnode1
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "false"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode1
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode1
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode1-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode1-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es1
            type: DirectoryOrCreate

---
#es1 portservice
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode1-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    nodePort: 9201
    targetPort: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    name: testnode1-9200
  - port: 9300
    nodePort: 9301
    targetPort: 9300
    protocol: TCP
    name: testnode1-9300
  selector:
    app: testnode1


---
#es1 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode1
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode1
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode1

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode2
  name: testnode2
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode2
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "true"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode2
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode2
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode2-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode2-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es2
            type: DirectoryOrCreate

---

#es1 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode2
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode2
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode2

----

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode3
  name: testnode3
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode3
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "true"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode3
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode3
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode3-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode3-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es3
            type: DirectoryOrCreate

---

#es3 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode3
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode3
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode3

---

#kibana dep
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kibana
  name: kibana
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: http://testnode1:9200
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
          value: http://testnode1:9200
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.8.0
        name: kibana
#      restartPolicy: Always

---
#kibana  dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kibana
---
#kibana port servi
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    nodePort: 5602
    targetPort: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    name: kibana
  selector:
    app: kibana

----

#elasticsearch-hq deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
  name: elasticsearch-hq
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch-hq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-hq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
        name: elasticsearch-hq
#      restartPolicy: Always

---
#elasticsearch-hq port service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-hq-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    nodePort: 8081
    targetPort: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    name: elasticsearch-hq
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
```

Comment: the `yaml` you have added works just fine for me...line 17 is `replicas: 1` for me; check if it is the same for you..

Comment: what kubernetes version are you using? Also do you mind me sharing my entire yaml file for you to try? yes replicas: 1 is the line 17 for me as well.

Comment: yes, I could give it a try...my kubernetes server version is `1.17` and `kubectl` client version is `1.15`.

Comment: I edited the post, the entire yaml is like the one above.

Comment: I also created another yaml with only the first version i shared here written in it. It didnt give any error outputs but the pod is in pending state for minutes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are couple of issues in the `yaml` file:

1. You have used four `-` in some places whereas the separator is three `-`.
2. Once, you fix the first issue, you'll see the following errors related to `NodePort` services as the valid range for the `nodePort` is `30000-32767`:

```
Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "testserver.yaml": Service "testnode1-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 9201: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "testserver.yaml": Service "kibana-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 5602: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
Error from server (Invalid): error when creating "testserver.yaml": Service "elasticsearch-hq-service" is invalid: spec.ports[0].nodePort: Invalid value: 8081: provided port is not in the valid range. The range of valid ports is 30000-32767
```

Fixing both the errors will resolve the `yaml` issues.

Below is the full working `yaml` file:

```
#namespace define
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: testlog

---
#esnodes
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode1
  name: testnode1
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode1
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "false"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode1
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode1
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode1-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode1-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es1
            type: DirectoryOrCreate


---
#es1 portservice
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode1-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode1
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 9200
    nodePort: 31201
    targetPort: 9200
    protocol: TCP
    name: testnode1-9200
  - port: 9300
    nodePort: 31301
    targetPort: 9300
    protocol: TCP
    name: testnode1-9300
  selector:
    app: testnode1



---
#es1 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode1
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode1
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode1

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode2
  name: testnode2
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode2
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "true"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode2
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode2
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode2-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode2-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es2
            type: DirectoryOrCreate

---

#es1 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode2
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode2
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode2

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: testnode3
  name: testnode3
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: testnode3
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: testnode3
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ES_JAVA_OPTS
          value: -Xms768m -Xmx768m
        - name: MAX_LOCKED_MEMORY
          value: unlimited
        - name: bootstrap.memory_lock
          value: "true"
        - name: cluster.initial_master_nodes
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: cluster.name
          value: testcluster
        - name: discovery.seed_hosts
          value: testnode1,testnode2,testnode3
        - name: http.cors.allow-origin
          value: "*"
        - name: network.host
          value: 0.0.0.0
        - name: node.data
          value: "true"
        - name: node.name
          value: testnode3
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch:1.8.0
        name: testnode3
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
          name: testnode3-claim0
#      restartPolicy: Always
      volumes:
        - name: testnode3-claim0
          hostPath:
            path: /logtest/es3
            type: DirectoryOrCreate

---
#es3 dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: testnode3
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: testnode3
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: testnode3

---

#kibana dep
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kibana
  name: kibana
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kibana
  template:
    metadata:
        app: kibana
    spec:
      containers:
      - env:
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_HOSTS
          value: http://testnode1:9200
        - name: ELASTICSEARCH_URL
          value: http://testnode1:9200
        image: amazon/opendistro-for-elasticsearch-kibana:1.8.0
        name: kibana
#      restartPolicy: Always

---
#kibana  dns
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  clusterIP: None
  selector:
    app: kibana
---
#kibana port servi
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kibana-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: kibana
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 5601
    nodePort: 31602
    targetPort: 5601
    protocol: TCP
    name: kibana
  selector:
    app: kibana

---
#elasticsearch-hq deployment
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
  name: elasticsearch-hq
  namespace: testlog
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: elasticsearch-hq
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: elasticsearch-hq
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: elastichq/elasticsearch-hq
        name: elasticsearch-hq
#      restartPolicy: Always

---
#elasticsearch-hq port service
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: elasticsearch-hq-service
  namespace: testlog
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
spec:
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 8081
    nodePort: 31081
    targetPort: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    name: elasticsearch-hq
  selector:
    app: elasticsearch-hq
```

Comment: Yes i encountered with the port problem at first then i changed the port setting on kube-apiserver.yaml then it was resolved. As you mentioned I fixed the seperators and now the yaml worked. However pods are still in pending status i'll have to look further for this. But as of my initial problem your reply solved the issue. Thanks.